# calculate price between dates according to set price and month

Tags: php, mysql

I am kind of stuck now and appreciate some help please.
I have a Mysql table with 2 columns "month" and "price" i.e. January >> 5 (Euro); February >> 7 (Euro) and so on. On the booking form of the website the user can select arrival date and departure date. If the user selects a date with months in between, say 20.01.2013-12.04.2013, how can one calculate the full months (02 and 03) in between?

This is what i have got to calculate the days in arrival and departure months:

```
 ...
 $query="SELECT * FROM pricecal";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 $num=mysql_numrows($result);

 $i=0;

 while ($i < $num)
  {

$month=mysql_result($result,$i,"month");
$price=mysql_result($result,$i,"price");

$i++;

$a = $_POST['dropToDay'];
$b = $_POST['dropToMonth'];
$c = $_POST['dropToYear'];
$d = $_POST['dropOffDay'];
$e = $_POST['dropOffMonth'];
$f = $_POST['dropOffYear'];

$days_to = (date('t',mktime(0, 0, 0, $a,(date($b) +1), date($c))) - $a +1);
$off_month_dif = (date('d-m-Y',mktime(0, 0, 0, $d,(date($e)), date($f))) - $d);
$days_off = (date('d-m-Y',mktime(0, 0, 0, $d,(date($e)), date($f))) - $off_month_dif);
$days = (date($f.$e.$d) - date($c.$b.$a));
$days_all = ($days+1);

if($b==$e AND $b==$month)
 {
  $b = $month;
  $pricing = $days_all*$price;
  echo 'Price for '.$days_all.' days is '.$pricing.' EUR.';
 }

if($b == $month AND $b != $e)
 {
  $pricing1 = $days_to*$price;
 }
if($e == $month AND $b != $e)
 {
  $pricing = $days_off*$price;
  $pricings_all = $pricing+$pricing1;
  echo 'Price for booking time: '.$pricings_all.' EUR';
 }
 .....
```

Comment: any table structure some sample data and desired output?

Comment: What output do you expect? If rate of march is 8 euro and april is 9 euro then what output you expect?

Comment: January rate = 5, Feb=7, Mar=5, Apr=3, so if user selected 20.01.2013-12.04.2013, then January is 12 days = 60 EUR + April 12 days = 36 EUR. I got those. but i cant get february and march. and obviously they are full months, so I need Jan 60 + Feb ?? + Mar ?? + Apr 36 = Total booking fee

Comment: Cuuld you post of whatever have you done till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an array of month and prices (I am assuming that you are storing *numeric* months):

```
$price = array();
$query = "SELECT month, price FROM pricecal";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $price[$result["month"]] = $result["price"];
}
// array(
// 1 => 5,
// 2 => 7,
// ...
// )
```

Next, build the two timestamps, loop through them and sum:

```
$ts1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['dropToMonth'],  $_POST['dropToDay'],  $_POST['dropToYear']);
$ts2 = mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['dropOffMonth'], $_POST['dropOffDay'], $_POST['dropOffYear']);

for($ts = $ts1, $sum = 0; $ts <= $ts2; $ts = strtotime("+1 day", $ts)) {
    $sum += $price[date("n", $ts)];
}
```

Comment: this looks good but i get an error message like Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\somefile\some.php on line 17 ..Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\somefile\some.php on line 17 ..Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\somefile\some.php on line 17 Resource id #6.... so it actually finds the months but for the error message. and why do i need an array if it got the prices in the table? the prices are changeable via admin so if they are in an array how will they change?

Comment: ok, i got it working now thats really great thank you so much :) ..just is there a possibility to pull the prices from the database table instead from the array because the prices need to be editable?

Comment: Of course the prices should be pulled from database; I never said that you hard code the array. The example builds the array on-demand by pulling info from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just assuming out loud. Is this what you are looking for? Something along this way?

[SQLFIDDLE MYSQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2741/20)

```
select months, price
from demo, (select @i:=-1) r
where months = 
  date_format(
    Date_Add(Date '2013.01.13',
             interval @i:=@i+1 month),'%b')
having @i <= period_diff(date_format
(Date '2013-04-12', '%Y%m'),
date_format(Date '2013-01-20', '%Y%m'))
;

| MONTHS | PRICE |
------------------
|    Jan |     5 |
|    Feb |     7 |
|    Mar |     9 |
|    Apr |    10 |
```

Comment: @ceyrslan please take a look at this sample and comment. Based on your comments we can go forward.

Comment: since im rather new to php/mysql, i dont really understand your suggestion. i basically need to calculate the price between arrival date and departure date for booking. i got it working so far (see my question at the top). my problem now is if the user selects in the form a date where a whole month or even more months are in between, then it needs to find those months and work out the total for each of them based on the daily rate of that month in the table. and the rates in the table are changeable by admin

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the total fee between two dates in a single query. The innermost sub-query looks a little scary, but it just creates a row for each day between a range. Then it groups by month.

**Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53b3b/1

#### Output:

```
447
```

#### Query:

```sql
SET @beginDate = '2013-01-20';
SET @endDate   = '2013-04-12';

SELECT
    SUM( days.days * rate.price ) AS fee

FROM
    rate

    INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT 
        MONTH( a.Date ) AS month,
        COUNT( * )      AS days

    FROM (
        select @endDate - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
        from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
        ) a

    WHERE 
        a.Date BETWEEN @beginDate AND @endDate 

    GROUP BY
        MONTH( a.Date )

    ) AS days
    ON rate.month = days.month
```

#### Schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE 
    rate 
    (
    month INT, 
    price INT
    );

INSERT INTO 
    rate
    ( 
    month, 
    price
    )

VALUES
    ( 1, 5 ),
    ( 2, 7 ),
    ( 3, 5 ),
    ( 4, 3 );
```